# How do restore side panel options in Geany?

Tags: geany

How do you restore the left-hand side-panel options in Geany? The buttons like "refresh", etc at the top of the file tree view?

I accidentally right-clicked something, and they disappeared, and I can't find where in Geany's immensely over-complicated preferences menu I can re-enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the *Tree Browser* sidebar and select from the pop-up menu:

> □ Show Toolbars

Comment: Thank you. I knew it must have been something trivial, but I wasn't seeing it.